# Disable parallel execution of "Clean solution" in .NET Core

Tags: .net-core, msbuild

We have a solution in .NET Core 3.1 with multiple project. All project have same build output.

This worked fine until recently a build start failing on all machines. (Some update?)

Build works
Rebuild fails.
Clean + Rebuild works.

I can reproduce the issue in Visual Studio and in the Rider as well.

The root cause is following:

Rebuild start building every project in parallel as separate task. Each task first delete output folder and then build a project.

Because all project have same output folder and run in parallel, they just delete files created by another project build which result into error:

```
  Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4919, 5): [MSB3030] Could not copy the file "C:\myproject\x64\Debug\Project1.deps.json" because it was not found.
  Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4919, 5): [MSB3030] Could not copy the file "C:\myproject\x64\Debug\Project1.runtimeconfig.json" because it was not found.
  Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4919, 5): [MSB3030] Could not copy the file "C:\myproject\x64\Debug\Project1.runtimeconfig.dev.json" because it was not found.
```

Obviously a simple solution would be to do separate output folder, but I cannot do this because another tools expect this structure and because it is kind of rule.

I would like to clean the output on rebuild first before each project clean+build is trigger.

Another solution I can imagine is to generate deps.json, runtimeconfigs files into separate folder.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Do you have created a test solution that reproduce the bug?

Comment: a bit of long shot, have you tried setting [project dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-and-remove-project-dependencies?view=vs-2019) in VS?

Comment: I have exactly the same issue with .NET 5 and VS 2019 version 16.10.1 when test project A depends on project C, test project B also depends on Project C.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you Can set project dependencies in solution properties... that way they should be forced to build one  after the other. eg. A depends on B , B on C

Comment: I have the same issue as Tomas when 2 test projects depends on the same project. The project dependencies shows the build order list of projects, but the issue remains.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably not change the build output paths, simply do a publish?